# Viewing only opened files in vscode instead of tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, settings

I'm recently installed VScode 1.61 in my Ubuntu and I use Sublime Text 4113 too. I would like to know if is possible set a sidebar in VScode the same way as I use in Sublime Text which is view only the opened files(note that is different that Explorer) rather than tabs on the top of the window and remember them after I restart the software.[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "Open Editors" view in the Explorer, which shows the currently opened files. Use the command `Explorer: Focus on Open Editors View` or click the `...` in the Explorer's upper right corner to show it.

[image: command]

[image: open editors]